# How do I tell a React Router Route to render......itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I have this huge issue I haven't been able to fix. Basically I have a single-page application with React that consists of Home.jsx. All the state, all the important stuff is right there. However, I recently figured out that I will need a second page that replaces the current one, like an second page that replaces the current page in view.

However, I never really thought I would need this, so all my stuff, everything, is in my Home.jsx file, all the state and all the functions, not in index.jsx which simply renders the app.

So here's the issue. Every single tutorial, every single video, all of them assume you can just work from index.jsx and configure the Routes there. **I can't, because the second page that will be rendered will need props to be passed to it, and all of this data is in Home.jsx.**

So I tried to fix this by doing all the routing from Home.jsx, but then I have the following issue - it simply doesn't work, because I thought I could easily do this by **within the Home.jsx file** doing:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
```

But, this of course is the current component i'm entering it in, **so I'm telling it to render itself.** This leads to my app loading forever until Chrome says Aw,Snap!, it probably turns into something of an infinite loop.

So, my question is, as I can't work from 'above' Home.jsx, I NEED to be able to within the render function of Home.jsx tell it that one route is Home.jsx itself, and the next route is Page2, but this seems impossible with Router.

Is there a way with Router, and if not, is there another way?

Comment: Typically there's a root component which renders the router and the pages are separate components. You seem to have merged the root component with a page component. I'd suggest you uncouple the two. Might need some rewrite but you'll end up with cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

So you'll usually have an App.js with the routes in.

```
const App = () => (

    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/otherpage" component={OtherPage}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
)
```

If you need the home to always run no matter, then you nest the a `<Router>` inside the home page:

```
const Home = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/otherpage" component={OtherPage}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```

Make sure in the App.js that you remove `exact` attribute from the Route

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y9jeq9

Finally, if you want to separate the actual home logic out so you don't mess up home rendering with router rendering then, just have another layer that has the routes and is loaded from the app. And that layer loads the home route + any other routes

Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kyut2w?file=index.js